# Volumes of the four heart chambers

Tags: human-anatomy, cardiology

We know that the left ventricle which feeds blood into the aorta is typically the largest chamber of the heart.

I'm looking for the typical absolute and relative sizes of the four heart chambers.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! It is expected that you do some researching on your own prior to posting the question. For example, have you tried the simple method of Googling your question? It gives you the answer [right away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtFu0.png).

Comment: which species are you after?

Comment: It's tagged human anatomy.

Comment: @Domen, That doesn't tell me because ml/m2 is not a measure of volume.

Comment: @David, the values are corrected for the person's height, so that the volumes are divided by $\rm height^2$. See for example [Fuchs, A. Normal values of left ventricular mass ... (2016)](https://academic.oup.com/ehjcimaging/article/17/9/1009/2237564).

Comment: @Domen, That requires further explanation, because why per height² and not per height or height³ which would be volume, which I might assume the heart volume scales with.

Comment: @David, we cannot discuss this in the comments. Please read the guidelines on [How to Ask a Question on StackExchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question accordingly, and someone will be able to write a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is not the same in all the organisms having four chambered heart. But if you are talking about humans, here are the measurements:

The mean volume of the right atrium (RAMV), right ventricle (RVMV), and left atrium (LAMV) was 22.3 +/- 6.5, 40.3 +/- 6.5 and 28.7 +/- 8.2 ml/m2, respectively.

Source: [Measurement of four chambers' volumes and ventricular masses by cardiac CT examination](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6678293/#:%7E:text=The%20%22mean%22%20volume%20of%20the,8.2%20ml%2Fm2%2C%20respectively.)

Comment: ml/m² is not a volume. What on earth is meant here?

Comment: It is Left Atrial End-Diastolic Volume Index. The unit ml/m² is used to define the size of the atrium with respect to the flow of blood.

Comment: ml/m2 is an indexed volume.

Answer (score 0):

From an echocardiographic perspective I direct you to the consensus statements in our field (1). Keep in mind echocardiographic measurements are generally considered less anatomically accurate compared to cardiac MRI or cardiac CT. Since you have asked for absolute and relative sizes I have mainly just included measurement indexed to BSA from which you can determine the absolute depending on the persons height and weight:

Page 7. Normal LV EDV (2-SD range):

62-150mL (Male), 46-106mL (Female)

P.39.e8 Normal ranges and severity partition cutoffs

[image: Normal and Abnormal LV ranges]

Page 10. Normal LA volume range (indexed to BSA):

16-34mL/m2 (Male), 16-34mL/m2 (Female)

Page 20. Normal RV EDV range (indexed to BSA):

35-87mL/m2 (Male), 32-74mL/m2 (Female)

Page 30. RA volume (indexed to BSA):

25±7mL/m2 (Male), 21±6mL/m2 (Female)

References:

1. Lang et al. 2015 "Recommendations for Cardiac Chamber Quantification in Adults: An Update from the American Society of Echocardiography and the European Association of Cardiovascular imaging" Journal of the American Society of Echocardiography.